# profiling and RtlUserThreadStart

Tags: windows, multithreading, profiling

I am profiling my multi-threaded application with the software "Sleepy". My threads are created through the windows API using a thread pool.

While profiling, it shows a very high amount of time spent in the following functions :
- RtlUserThreadStart (time spent : 46% exclusive, 100% inclusive)
- ZwWaitForMultipleObjects (23% exclusive, 23% inclusive)
- NtWaitForMultipleOvjects (15.4% exclusive, 15.4% inclusive)
- NtDelayExecution (7.7% exclusive, 7.7% inclusive)
- TpWaitForWork (5.8% exclusive, 5.8% inclusive)
- my actual computations (about 2% inclusive).

However, I am not sure whether these thread handling functions are in fact the result of my computations or just some "wasted time" (is RtlUserThreadStart exactly the entry point of my callback functions, in which case the multithreading would be good ?).

In short, does these data show that my multi-threading is useless or not ?

Thanks !

Comment: Well, doesn't look good, does it?  If you made your own threadpool then it isn't working well.

Comment: I don't know - that is the question... Does it show that it doesn't work well ? Or is  RtlUserThreadStart the entry point of my callback ? (which would show it does work well). I don't use my own threadpool but the one in windows API. And the code works much faster on Linux with gcc using OpenMP instead (although on another machine, so it is hard to compare)...
On windows, it is slow whether I use windows' threadpool or windows' CreateThread functions.

Comment: Any idea what the CPU load for your process is? probably quite low. The functions *WaitForMultipleObjects usually consume lot's of time but almost no CPU cycles just because they do what they do: waiting..

Comment: The CPU usage was pretty low. But I would have like to get an idea of the efficiency just based on these data, without looking at the CPU. The CPU load can be low for other reasons (like allocating a lot of memory) than the pure parallelization overhead (the calls to CreateThread etc.). For this code, the parallelization works much better on Linux :s

Comment: Any news on this?